# Passing parameters to actions in redux (Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

this is my action

```
export function removeColor(color) {
  return {
    type: C.REMOVE_COLOR,
    payload: color
  }
}
```

this is my reducer

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case C.REMOVE_COLOR:
    return [...state.slice(action.payload + 1)]
  }

  return state
}
```

this is where i dispatch the action. Display colors calls remove colors from array which passes the index to the action.

```
removeColorFromArray(index) {
    this.props.removeColor(index)
  }

  displayColors(color, index) {
    return(
      <ul key={index}>
        <li>{color}</li>
        <button onClick={this.removeColorFromArray(index)}>Remove Color</button>
      </ul>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div>Colors</div>
        <button onClick={this.props.showColorForm}>Add Color</button>
        <ColorForm />
        { this.props.colors.map(this.displayColors) }
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I continuously get this warning

`Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within`render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

What I trying to do is take the array position of the item selected and remove it from the state, but am having a difficult time achieving this. Can you see where I am going wrong or what I could do differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this string:

```
<button onClick={this.removeColorFromArray(index)}>Remove Color</button>
```

to:

```
<button onClick={this.removeColorFromArray.bind(this, index)}>Remove Color</button>
```

You should pass to event-props (`onChange`, `onFocus`, etc.) the function, not the result of the function invocation.

Comment: thanks a bunch! how would you pass parameters to the function in that situation though?

Comment: Parameters are passed after the first argument `funcName.bind(this, param1, param2, param3)`. Here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/bind-method-function-javascript docs for `bind` and some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Or use arrow function:

```
<button onClick={this.removeColorFromArray(index)}>Remove Color</button>
```

to:

```
<button onClick={() => this.removeColorFromArray(index)}>Remove Color</button>
```